# iterm2 log output garbled

Tags: terminal, iterm2, iterm

I am using iterm2 as my primary terminal on mac. The iterm2 was enabled **Automatically log session input to files in:** to capture the terminal output to a file.

The output can be captured from the terminal session but it looks like iterm2 captured some key binding output. May I know how can I set a log session only capture what I see in the terminal instead of below my example out?

[image]

```
[?1034h(env) mac:~ user$ 
(env) mac:~ user$ 
(env) mac:~ user$ bash
[?1034hbash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ this is my output
bash: this: command not found
bash-3.2$ for i in 1[K(1..100); [K[K do [K[K[K[Kl [K[K; do echo $i [K; done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash-3.2$ for i in (1..100); do echo $i; done[1P[1@s[1@e[1@q[1@([1@*[1P[C[C[C[C[1P[1P[1@,
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash-3.2$ for i in seq(1,100); do echo $i; done[1P[C[1P[1P[1P[1P[1P[1P[1P[1P[1P[1@{[1@1[1@.[1@.[1@1[1@0[1@0[1@}

bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ bash -login
[?1034h(env) mac:~ user$ 
(env) mac:~ user$ 
(env) mac:~ user$ 
(env) mac:~ user$ 
[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[Clazyman [K
(env) mac:~ user$ lsfj;askjkjfunction lazyman(){ git -C ${gitrepo} add .; git -C ${gitrepo} commit -a -m "$(date) ${1}"; }
[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[Clazyman [K[10@source lazyman.sh[C[1@bash -x[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[Cenv[Ksource bash_profile 
(env) mac:~ user$ 
(env) mac:~ user$
```